# Django : how to change the value of a field or update the field in model / Db .?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have two models,  Car and Booking. A Car is a ForeignKey field in Booking model. If Car is booked, it's removed from Car list.
After car is booked the code changes to is_available_car = false. And then car is not showing in Car listview. but the 
Problem i am facing is:

1. After i removed booking from admin, the car is not showing in list view.  if the car booking is closed i want to make  is_available_car = True. I can't seem to change it from false to true.
2. I added a filter query to make is_available_car = True. Problem is after car is returned and booking time finished, I have to manually change the value of is_available_car = True every time.

Help me out please that if car booking is finished or i delete the booking .the car available value changes to true !!

These are my models and views:

**Models**

```
class Booking(models.Model):

booking_name = models.CharField(max_length=240, null=False)
customer_name = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='book_customers' )
book_car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='book_car')
rental_price = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
times_pick = models.TimeField(blank=True)
is_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.booking_name

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("buggy_app:detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})


 class Car(models.Model):

reg_no = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True)
model_year = models.DateField()
car_name =models.CharField(max_length=40)
car_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='cars', blank = True)
is_available_car = models.BooleanField(default = False)

     def __str__(self):
       return self.car_name

   def get_absolute_url(self):
      return reverse("buggy_app:details",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

**Views**

```
class BookingView(FormView):
template_name = 'buggy_app/booking.html'
form_class = BookingForm
models = Booking
def form_valid(self, form):
    car_id = self.request.GET.get('car', '')
    car = Car.objects.get(id=car_id)
    car.is_available_car = False
    car.save()
    form.save()
    return super(BookingView, self).form_valid(form)


success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    # kwargs['car'] is the car booking now!
    try:
        kwargs['car'] = Car.objects.get(id=self.request.GET.get('car', ''))
    except (Car.DoesNotExist, ValueError):
        kwargs['car'] = None
    return super(BookingView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)


 class CarListView(ListView):
       context_object_name = 'cars'
       model = models.Car

       def get_queryset(self):
           qs = super(CarListView, self).get_queryset()
           qs = qs.filter(is_available_car=True)
           return qs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a signal handler that listens to the `pre_delete` signal for the `Booking` model: see the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signals/). So everytime a booking is deleted, your signal handler will be called and you'll be able to update the corresponding car.

e.g.

```
@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Booking):
def update_car(sender, **kwargs):
    car = sender.book_car
    car.is_available = True
    car.save()
```

Then make sure you register your handler as described in the Django docs above.

Now I don't know what you mean by "when a booking is finished", but that sounds just like a method on the Booking model itself:

```
def finish(self):
    self.expired = True  # You'd have to define what it means for a booking to be finished
    car = self.book_car
    car.is_available = True
    car.save()
```

Comment: hi thankyou for the solution . finished is not a method . i meant to say i am having a car booking start time and end time. when the time finish . it shows to the listview.

Comment: @dirkgorten  i dont know about signal . i am beginner in web development and django . what do i do . save the code of yours to my views ?

Comment: Sir can you write me the handler also . i am new to programming and dont know about signals also /